# Suggestions for a curriculum for someone who wants to shift career paths into Computer Science from a Different Domain

Tags: computer-science

One of my friends is currently following a business management degree and now would like to switch study and career paths into Software Engineering. He asked a proper roadmap to follow since I am also following a CS degree. I would like to get suggestions from the experienced community.

Comment: FYI This type of question (i.e opinion based) isn't appropriate for SO - you may want to post it on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Apologies if so and thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Switching from Business Management to Software Engineering: Roadmap and Suggestions

Switching from a business management background to software engineering is an exciting transition with great potential. Here is a roadmap and some suggestions to help your friend successfully navigate this career shift:

1. **Acquire a Solid Foundation in Computer Science:**
   Since your friend is currently pursuing a business management degree, it would be beneficial to gain a strong understanding of computer science fundamentals. They can start by taking online courses or enrolling in a part-time computer science program to learn programming languages, algorithms, data structures, and other core concepts. This foundation will provide them with the necessary knowledge for a successful transition.
2. **Learn Programming Languages:**
   Software engineering heavily relies on programming languages. Encourage your friend to start with widely used languages like Python, Java, or JavaScript. These languages have vast communities, resources, and job opportunities. Learning the basics and gradually expanding their proficiency in these languages will be crucial.
3. **Master Data Structures and Algorithms (DSA):**
   Data Structures and Algorithms form the backbone of software engineering. Your friend should focus on understanding different data structures (arrays, linked lists, stacks, queues, trees, graphs, etc.) and algorithms (sorting, searching, graph traversal, etc.). They can explore Kunal Kushwaha's free DSA course available on YouTube, which provides comprehensive coverage of DSA topics.
4. **Build Practical Projects:**
   Practical experience is invaluable in the software engineering field. Encourage your friend to work on personal projects that align with their interests. This hands-on experience will allow them to apply what they've learned, gain problem-solving skills, and build a portfolio to showcase their abilities to potential employers.
5. **Expand Knowledge through Online Resources:**
   Online platforms like Coursera, Udemy, and edX offer a wide range of courses specifically tailored to software engineering. Your friend can explore these platforms to learn about different areas such as web development, mobile app development, databases, and software testing. Additionally, encourage them to participate in coding challenges and open-source projects to enhance their skills and collaborate with other developers.
6. **Network and Join Communities:**
   Engaging with the software engineering community is crucial for learning, sharing knowledge, and exploring job opportunities. Your friend can join online forums, developer communities, and attend tech conferences or meetups to connect with experienced professionals. Participating in hackathons or coding competitions can also help them expand their network and gain exposure to real-world problem-solving scenarios.
7. **Pursue Internships or Entry-Level Positions:**
   Internships and entry-level positions are excellent opportunities to gain practical experience and learn from experienced software engineers. Encourage your friend to actively search for these positions, even if they require some flexibility in terms of compensation or location. The focus should be on acquiring hands-on experience and building a professional network within the software engineering industry.
8. **Consider Further Education:**
   Depending on the level of commitment and long-term goals, your friend might consider pursuing a formal degree in computer science or a related field. This option can provide a more comprehensive education and potentially open up advanced career opportunities in research, development, or management roles.

Remember, transitioning from one field to another requires dedication, continuous learning, and persistence. Encourage your friend to stay motivated and remain open to learning new technologies, methodologies, as well as data structures and algorithms. Kunal Kushwaha's free DSA course can be a valuable resource for mastering DSA concepts.

Best of luck to your friend on their journey to becoming a software engineer!

Comment: Did you generate this by an AI?

Comment: I've done it grammatically corrected with AI